# open source SATA to DDR2 SDRAM adater

Tags: pcb, fpga, sdram, dram, sata

I want to learn how computer memory sticks can be used as secondary storage using some intermediate FPGA for data processing. Actually I want to design a PCB myself. I'm good with PCB designing but I don't know anything about this device. I did some research on the internet but couldn't find some open-source designs and schematics. So it would be great if someone points me to directions. I need SATA to DRAM adapter reference design like [this one](https://techreport.com/review/16255/acards-ans-9010-serial-ata-ram-disk/). Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid you'd have to do this yourself from ground up, including the FPGA code. However, I can't see any benefit in doing this, apart from the learning experience/reuse of old hardware. A good modern SSD would already be _as fast as this,_ and the storage would be persistent, let alone cheaper to get. Also, SATA would bottleneck the DRAM's performance, the same way it does for SSDs. There also were similar products using PCIe too, but those never took off either.

Comment: There are some open source FPGA boards, at least one based on the Zynq FPGA.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you. Can you please provide some links or something?

Comment: I would have to search for them; but given the selection of words in my last comment, I think you can do that equally well.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.